# HTML Searchbar click in excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am really stuck trying to write a piece of VBA code and could really use some help!  I want to navigate to a specific website (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/), type in a value into the searchbar, and then hit "Search".  I cannot get my code to properly hit the search button.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer 
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement
Dim oSearchButton As Object
Dim SearchElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim oResult As Object, Element As Object, myLink As Object

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Set Doc = objIE.Document
End With

Set oSearch = objIE.Document.forms("searchbox").elements("q")
    oSearch.Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value
Set oSearchButton = objIE.Document.forms("searchbox").getElementsByTagName("input")

    objIE.Navigate oSearchButton
```

Right now, my code simply navigates to a google search for: [object HTMLInputElement]

the HTML for the search button is as follows:

```
<form name="searchbox" action="/search/q.php" method="POST">
    <input name="q" style="width: 90px; font-weight: bold;" type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search..."></form>
**<input type="submit" value="Search...">**
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  thank you very much!

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns multiple objects, and you are trying to set that as a single object.

Comment: not related to your issue, but you should not be referring to `objIE` inside a `with objIE` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.
As mentioned in the comments `getElementsByTagName` returns multiple objects. In your case you want to refer to the second one like so:
`objIE.Document.forms("searchbox").getElementsByTagName("input")(1)`

Secondly, the `Navigate` just takes IE to a url. You want to click the button so just do:
`objIE.Document.forms("searchbox").getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Click`

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you.  But something still stumps me:  This code works when I step through it using f8.  but when I run through it automatically using f5 it takes me to a different website than the one I want.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why!  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it works for me. Maybe if you give more details on the error someone can help.